# ECIES secure mode and padding scheme for ECC Algorithm -Java

Tags: java, encryption, padding, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

What is the best secure mode and padding scheme for ECIES replacement.

```
 Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");
```

```
public static  byte[] eccEnc(String msg,String pub) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        //get the public key from public key text
        byte[] enKeyByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pub);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecPb = new X509EncodedKeySpec(enKeyByte);
        PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpecPb);

        //Impl
        byte[] d = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        byte[] e = new byte[]{8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        IESParameterSpec param = new IESParameterSpec(d, e, 256);

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey, param);

        byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
        byte[] cipher = c.doFinal(message);
        System.out.println(new String(cipher));
        return cipher;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved by Cipher.getInstance("ECIES/None/NoPadding", "BC");